# Negative ItemCount in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

What can be done about negative numbers in library item counts? ItemCount is a read-only property, what are you supposed to do when it is drastically incorrect?

Earlier last week, I was doing some testing involving the copying and moving of files and folders from one document library to another. I was transfering the items from our actual document library to a sandbox "Test" library that I used to run all sorts of object model and workflow testing in before migrating to the public lists and libraries. I noticed that with files, things worked correctly, but when I copied a folder that had a file inside it (using `SPFolder.CopyTo()`), the item count for the test library did not actually update. Since this testing was mostly playing around, I paid it little heed.

Today I was back in the test library to test a different workflow (regarding PDF conversion). While I was there, I decided to delete the folder I left last week since I didn't need it anymore. And that's when I saw the item count for the list drop to -1 in the All Site Content View. When I deleted the new PDF I had just uploaded, it then dropped to -2! I even checked with the object model... getting an instance of the library I checked the ItemCount property... lo and behold it was also -2.

Is there any process which runs in the background, kinda like the one that cleans up workflow history, which will correct this kind of issue? Or is a programmer expected to keep watch for this kind of situation and come up with calculations to compensate the "count penalty", as it were?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of references on the web about similar things to this.  Example:
http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/negative-item-count-in-document-libraries/

You are most likely running into bugs in the SharePoint software or you are using the Object Model in ways that MS never intended.

Comment: Works for me. Link was quite useful, too, in knowing how it is addressed. It is an unfortunate situation, but I can see why MS didn't consider that people might move entire folder structures from one library to another, rather than individual documents at a time to destination folders. Thanks!